# Background-image with linear-gradient on body not showing with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've been searching for a bit why my background is not showing up, ill start with my bg css:

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient
  (to right, #0F2027, #203A43, #2C5364, #2C5364, #203A43, #0F2027) !important;
}
```

When I inspect element my html and body both have a width of 0px which is why it's not showing I guess.

I use Bootstrap 3 and removing it from my page does fix the issue but I use Bootstrap for a lot so that doesn't really work for me.

One cheap fix I use currently is creating a span inside the body tag with a single character and then making it's opacity 0 and hiding it in a corner but obviously this should only be temporary.

I've tried background-color which does work so I'm guessing there is some conflict between Bootstrap 3 and background-image or linear-gradient.

Does anyone know of a proper way to fix this issue?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, I realize if the body width is 0px it can't show my bg but what's causing my body width to be 0px?

EDIT2: Added HTML for reproduction:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<htmL>
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </htmL>
```

Comment: Background only appears if your content have some width and height, otherwise it doesn't appears, background has not a "physical" width or height, its not like an image.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the bg shows when bootstrap is removed. Maybe Bootstrap is changing my bodies width to 0px but that seems like an odd thing for it do.

Comment: @kevinfromspace Do you have a new-Line in your source-code after linear-gradient? If so, remove it and write all in one line

Comment: check the css on your body.

Comment: do you not have any content?

Comment: @Stender The issue is not having any content, but why it does this regardless

Comment: @D.Schaller I tried putting it all in one line and removing all other CSS, didn't fix it

Comment: @kevinfromspace Can you upload a screenshot of your dev-tools with all CSS rules on the body? Maybe we'll find an answer in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is causing this behaviour is the rule `margin:0` from **normalize.less**.

If you set the `margin` of the `body` to any value except `0`, the `background-image` will render.

```
body {
  margin: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F2027, #203A43, #2C5364, #2C5364, #203A43, #0F2027);
}
```

Comment: That actually fixed it, I'm also seeing no change other then the bg working now so does setting the body margin to 1px actually do anything?

Comment: @kevinfromspace It does something, it sets the `margin`, which you don't see whithout any content in it. The body represents the complete window and fills it in this case. Try adding a `<h1>Test</h1>` and play with the `margin` to see the differences.

Comment: @D.Schaller the body doesn't represent the complete window, here you are facing a background propagation

Comment: @kevinfromspace check this one and you will understand what is happening : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502338/how-to-remove-the-stripes-that-appears-when-using-linear-gradient-property/48503609#48503609 .. the *to right* direction is hidding the trick, use *to top* and see the difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif Whoopsie, then I should consider to talk about this with my teacher again. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to remove a space after "linear-gradient". This css property should be written like this linear-gradient() and in the brackets you can put your code. The overall code should be like below.

```
body {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F2027, #203A43, #2C5364, #2C5364, #203A43, #0F2027) !important;}
```

Comment: I don't need to