# Why does the linear-gradient disappear when I make an element position:absolute?

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I made a gradient background and I want to centralize this block of text. My objetive is to create a header that centralizes in the middle of the screen no matter the resolution of the viewport.

So I made this header an absolute position and used this centralization method I found online. It centralized perfectly, the problem is, the gradient background turns white (looks like the header is above the background on the body, I don't know).
I've already tried using position fixed, but the problem persists, other types of position don't centralize.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #B7B0F6, #B1D5F9);
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</header>
```

You can run the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Jhugorn/dsknqp7x/1/
If you take out the header in the CSS, the background appears just fine.
How can I make the background appear and centralize this element at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some height to the body to see the background:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #B7B0F6, #B1D5F9);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</header>
```

Your body contain no in-flow element so its height is equal to `0` (same thing for  the `html` height) and this will make the background  with a size of `0` thus you will see nothing.

You are not obliged to give a height of `100vh`. Even a small padding can be enough due [to background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background). The visual won't be exactly the same but you will hardly notice this in this case.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #B7B0F6, #B1D5F9);
  padding:5px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</header>
```

A small padding on the html too is fine:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #B7B0F6, #B1D5F9);

}
html {
  padding:2px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</header>
```

A big padding will make things look different!

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #B7B0F6, #B1D5F9);

}
html {
  padding:40px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</header>
```

---

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503609/8620333) to better understand how the propagation is done and how it works with gradient.

Comment: And that explanation about the element without inflow height gave me a lot of insight on how CSS understands elements, this helped me very much, thank you!