# Why is <!DOCTYPE html> changing page layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, doctype

I was writing a web page with a background image. Here is the CSS for that:

```
body {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-image: url("Images/page-background.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

That worked fine; the image had the same dimensions as the page. I then realised that I had forgotten to include `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html, so I added, because I thought that it wouldn't change anything. When I loaded the page back up again, the background image was repeated everywhere, all over the page. Can anyone explain why this has happened, and what I can do to fix it? Is removing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` again actually ok, or is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: Backgrounds repeat by default. See `background-repeat`

Comment: DIfferent doctypes have different default behaviors, because of changes to the HTML standard over time. That's the whole point of this tag, to allow you to select the version you want.

Comment: Does your html document literally include `<head>` and `<body>` tags? I suspect that on your first attempt, your browser considered your content to be a pure image (the same kind of interpretation which occurs when right-clicking an image, and saying "open in new tab") whereas with the `<!DOCTYPE>` you forced chrome to render as an html document

Comment: I tried adding background-repeat: no-repeat; and the image didn't have the same dimensions of the web page. is there something else I could do? And yes it does include head and body tags.

Comment: Is removing the <!DOCTYPE html> ok? Without it, will the web page look different for different browsers?

Comment: try:
    background-image: url("Images/page-background.png");
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

Comment: Thanks for the comment! What does vh do as a matter of understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a single image showing at the full size of the browser, even if you have a `<!DOCTYPE>` (which I recommend you *do* include, as it's better practice):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
body {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Square_definition.svg/178px-Square_definition.svg.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note it's important to make sure that `html` and `body` elements have 100% size (and to remove any default margin + padding added by browser).

Note I used a random example image.

EDIT: D.Pardal rightfully pointed out that this answer does not explain the difference observed.

Most of the explanation comes from the fact that:

- Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` puts the document into "standards mode"
- "Standards mode" dictates that the `body` element's height defaults to the minimum size needed to contain its content

The original version without `<!DOCTYPE html>` has a `<body>` which fills the page. Applying a background-image to this `<body>`, with `background-size: 100% 100%` fills the entire page. Adding the `DOCTYPE` shrinks the `body`'s height.

**"Why is the image visible at all if its height is equal to the `<body>`'s height of 0?"**

Because the body has default margins, applied by the browser, and these count towards the height of the background-image.

**"Why wasn't the image repeating in the first place?"**

It was repeating! The first repetition, however, was big enough to fill the entire parent. This can be verified by removing the `DOCTYPE` and shrinking the image's size to `background-size: 20% 20%;`.

Comment: Does not explain *why*.

Comment: Thanks very much @Gershom for the answer. This didn't work initially, but then I changed 'background-size: contain;' to 'background-size: 100% 100%;' and it worked! Thanks very much.

Comment: @PrimeCubed you should not make the html and body element position:absolute this is a very bad idea and it's not needed at all. All you need is this: https://jsfiddle.net/bt75cvx6/ (or https://jsfiddle.net/bt75cvx6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As I explained here: [How to remove the stripes that appears when using linear gradient property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48502338/8620333) You are facing a complex background propagation when setting the `bacground-size:100% 100%` with the doctype added:

```css
body {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Square_definition.svg/178px-Square_definition.svg.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The same will happen with a gradient coloration because a gradient will have a size `100% 100%` by default:

```css
body {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,red,blue);
}
```

---

To fix your issue you simply need to make sure the `html` element is at least `height:100%`

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
}

body {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Square_definition.svg/178px-Square_definition.svg.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

---

If you remove the doctype will fall into [the quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/8620333) and things will behave differently but you should not really care about this because you **must** add the doctype to your document: