# Can I make a nice blur transition in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a blur effect in the background of my website. But you can see that the transition is really cutted and I would like to have a nice fade.

```
.ug-background_shader{
filter: blur(250px);
background-color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
height: 70%;
width: 80%;
// background-color:  radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 8, 8, 0.733) 40%, rgb(177, 30, 30) 100%);d
position: fixed;
// z-index: -2;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%)}
```

[image: Can I make this effect a little bit more clean without the edges]

Comment: Please attach your html and css with code snippet.

Comment: Remove `filter: blur(250px);`?

Comment: I want to have blur effect but right now the the transition is really bad.

Comment: Ok, so you dont want a blur that you want? I'm confused

Comment: You can see that there are slight cuts in the transition so the blur effect is not really clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remove `filter : blur(250px)`. Recommended blur value is near 5px.

Simply place an image in that place. It's way better if you don't want to see those low quality lines.

See this [How can I prevent CSS gradient banding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666395/how-can-i-prevent-css-gradient-banding)

Comment: Thank you for that helpful comment. I would upvote but I lost all of my points because people downvoted my question :(

Comment: Oh no problem. I rarely visit stackoverflow so I'm happy I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `filter : blur(250px)`

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I would like to have a clean transition from black to grey.