# CSS Radial gradiant or filter blur makes appear lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a "light spot" effect on a website by using a div containing a white circle.

```
.spot {
   background-color: #e0e2e411;
   border-radius: 9999px;
   filter: blur(80px);
   /* background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ffffffff, #ffffffb9, #ffffff77, #ffffff3b, 
    #ffffff00, #ffffff00, #ffffff00); */
 }
```

But I'm getting demarcation lines that are really messing up the design.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  color:gray;
}

.spot {
  background-color: #ffffffff;
  filter: blur(220px);
  /* background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #ffffffff, #ffffffb9, #ffffff77, #ffffff3b, #ffffff00, #ffffff00, #ffffff00); */
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.target{
  border: 1px gray solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  right: -80px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h3>(you will need to look closer to see the lines)</span>
  <div class="container relative">
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="circle spot"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with an `svg > circle`, with a `radial-gradient` but I can't rid of it...

The circle takes all screen on the website, it really looks bad...
[image]

Is there any way to make it look better ?
Thanks

Note: If I zoom into the snipped full page:
[image]

Comment: I do not get that effect when I run your code. Please make a runnable snippet and test it shows the problem.

Comment: Can you: click on `Run code snippet` then `Full page` and zoom in page like `300%` you should see it much better. I see it on the little snippet I made above but its not that easy to see I agree.

Comment: No, I don't see any lines - full page and various zoom levels tried. Both on Windows10 Edge and IOS Safari it's all fine. What browser/OS/device are you using? Do you have any display settings?

Comment: Damned... I'm on `Windows 10 Pro, build 10.0.19045`, tried on last version of `edge` / `firefox` and `chrome`. I have a `32inch` monitor `MSI G32CQ4` with a resolution of `2560 x 1440` zoomed on `100%`(original) . And an old `GTX 770`

But you don't see the lines on the screenshot at the end of the question's post?

Comment: Yes, I see the lines on the screenshot, but I don’t see lines when I run the code.

Comment: Just  realised that I wasn't running your actual snippet, which shows me a solid dark gray only, but my own rendition of your original code with the linear-gradient uncommented. Does running the snippet as you have it show you any sort of light?

Comment: I believe that's just how gradients are rendered on Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: @AHaworth, yes, if I run the snippet from my post I can clearly see the lines where i putted the white box. (Just need to zoom a little in the page as the rectangle is really little). But i can clearly see them when i go full page ! :/ (I will edit with a new screenshot)

Comment: This phenomenon is called "banding": that might help you searching.

Answer (score 1):

The color banding is a typical issue of cross browser inconsistencies. Have seen it on many computers, now without me trying to answer why this happens and how to mitigate it, have a look at the answer here
[How can I prevent CSS gradient banding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666395/how-can-i-prevent-css-gradient-banding)